# ページをスクレイピングしようと文字コードエラーがでます

Tags: r

[この](http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/4/)ウエブページをスクレイピングしたいんですが、`rvest`を用いてやろうと以下のエラーがでます：

```
library(rvest)
URL = 'http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/4/'
read_html(URL)
```

> Error in `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)` : 
>     input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xFA 0xB1 0x90 0xE7 [6003]

同じサイトからそれ以外のページは問題はありません、例えば：

```
read_html('http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/2/')
# {xml_document}
# <html>
# [1] <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">\n  <meta charset="shi ...
# [2] <body id="container">&#13;\n<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11 ...
```

[これ](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/117)(英語）を読んで文字コードを調べようとしました：

```
library(httr)
guess_encoding(content(GET(URL), 'raw'))
#     encoding language confidence
# 1 ISO-8859-1       pt       0.72
# 2 ISO-8859-2       ro       0.44
# 3      UTF-8                0.10
# 4  Shift_JIS       ja       0.10
# 5    GB18030       zh       0.10
# 6     EUC-JP       ja       0.10
# 7     EUC-KR       ko       0.10
# 8       Big5       zh       0.10
# 9 ISO-8859-9       tr       0.01
```

でもその中二つだけが日本語です。その二つも同じエラーをだせます：

```
read_html(URL, encoding = 'Shift_JIS')
```

> Error in `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)` : 
>     input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xFA 0xB1 0x90 0xE7 [6003]

```
read_html(URL, encoding = 'EUC-JP')
```

> Error in `eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos)` : 
>     input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x8F 0x54 0x8A 0xD4 [6003]

このページ`Shift_JIS`/`EUC-JP`意外の文字コードに当たりませんか？

下手の日本語申し訳ありません。よろしくお願いいたします!

Comment: シフトJISで`0xFA 0xB1 0x90 0xE7` は、`﨑千`です。そのページの赤﨑千夏さん名前の一部ですね。 コード自体はシフトJISであってますが、いわゆる異体字で変換テーブルを持っていないのでしょう。[﨑](http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/ufa11), [千](http://glyphwiki.org/wiki/u5343-ue0100)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、 IANA定義の`Shift_JIS`はJIS X0208:1997の文字を含むと定められており、Windows拡張文字である`0xFA 0xB1`(`﨑`)は含まれていません。IANA定義に厳密に従う処理系ではそのような文字は処理できないので、「シフトJISであってます」というのは誤解を招く表現だと思います。rを試せる環境が手元にないのですが、`'Windows-31J'`、(IANAには未登録のようですが)`'Shift_JISX0213'`または`'Shift_JIS-2004'`を試してみるべきでしょう。

Comment: @OOPer `Windows-31J`も`Shift_JISX0213`も成功しました(`Shift_JIS-2004`もしっぱいでした)。詳しい情報ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

訂正：OOPerさんの指摘通り、このウェブページの文字コードはShift_JISではなく[Windows-31J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_943)でした。[CP932](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932)を指定して`read_html(URL,encoding = "cp932")`でもいけるようです。ということで以下の回答は的外れなものです。失礼しました。。

<del>上でコメントされているように、この文字が引っかかっているようですね。文字コードはShift_JISであっています。</del>

```
rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xFA, 0xB1, 0x90, 0xE7)))
[1] "﨑千"
```

<del>これがrvestのバグなのかはよくわかりませんが、以下のように`httr::GET()`でUTF-8のテキストとしてダウンロードしたあとに`read_html()`するとうまくいくようです。</del>

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

x <- GET('http://www.oricon.co.jp/rank/js/w/2017-01-16/p/4/')
x_text <- content(x, as = "text")

# 文字コードはUTF-8になる
Encoding(x_text)
#> [1] "UTF-8"

x_xml <- read_html(x_text)

x_nodes <- x_xml %>%
  html_nodes("section.box-rank-entry > div > a > div > p")

# このノードの「﨑千」がエラーになっていたが、今回はきちんと表示できる
x_nodes[7] %>%
  html_text()
#> [1] "川島瑞樹(CV:東山奈央),日野茜(CV:赤﨑千夏),堀裕子(CV:鈴木絵理),上田鈴帆(CV:春野ななみ),難波笑美(CV:伊達朱里紗)"
```

<del>`sessionInfo`は以下です。</del>

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932    LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] httr_1.2.1      rvest_0.3.2     xml2_1.0.0.9001
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#> [1] selectr_0.3-1 magrittr_1.5  R6_2.2.0      tools_3.3.2   curl_2.3      Rcpp_0.12.8   stringi_1.1.2 stringr_1.1.0 XML_3.98-1.5
```

Comment: `sessionInfo()`加わってくれませんか？`content(x, as = "text")`は`NA`です。

Comment: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","ja_JP.UTF-8")`をやっても`rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xFA, 0xB1, 0x90, 0xE7)))`は`"\xfa\xb1\x90\xe7"`になります。

Comment: sessionInfo()を追記しました。お使いのOSはMacでしょうか？ 私はWindowsなのでデフォルトの文字コードがShift_JISになっています。おそらくWindows以外でも動くと思うんですけど、追加でオプションが必要そうですね。

Comment: 奇妙ですね。全てのパッケージをupdateしても、R3.3.2インストールしても、エラーがガンコに続いてます。。。

Comment: 私はデフォルトのlocaleがたまたまShift_JIS（`Japanese_Japan.932`）なのでこのコードで動くんですが、ほかのlocaleの場合はうまく動かなそうですね。。すみません。ちょっと時間があるときにほかの環境を用意して調べます。

Comment: 僕Linux Mint(Ubuntuに関する)です。。。

Comment: Linuxでしたか。情報ありがとうございます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。[ここ](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales)によりますと、`Japanese_Japan.932`と`ja_JP.UTF-8`が同じです。

Comment: 本来の問題は既に解決している様ですが、`iconv()` を使ってみてはどうですか。`iconv(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xFA, 0xB1, 0x90, 0xE7))), from="Windows-31J", to="UTF-8")`